# SQL Server 2014 Round Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I read this MSDN page for `ROUND` function: [ROUND (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

When I run this example from above page, the result of my is not same as MSDN result:

MSDN:

```
SELECT ROUND(123.4545, 2)  -->  123.45
```

My result:

```
 SELECT ROUND(123.4545, 2)  -->  123.4500
```

There are two extra zeros in my result. Where is the problem? I want to have MSDN result.

Thanks

Comment: Look at example B and you'll see exactly the result you're seeing. I wouldn't look at example E (nor D) unless you're using "Azure SQL Data Warehouse Public Preview and Parallel Data Warehouse", since that's the section they're under

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have given 4 decimals so you would get results in 4 decimals.

Try like this,

```
SELECT convert(DECIMAL(8, 2), ROUND(123.4545, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks but Why MSDN result has 2 digit decimal?

Comment: @Arian because even MSDN is not that perfect :)